# python ActiveEXE(vb6) cross-event

Tags: python, vb6, activex, win32com

1. Declare, the vbcom was Global variable
2. After, vbcom was closed(use vb close button)
   but, the vbcom process is activating , Certainly!
3. Then, declare the vbcom was local variable
   but, a function(py2vb button) is not operating...
4. ASK!!!

   - When the vbcom is local variable
   - How do I write the **code to operate the py2vb button**

[ActiveX EXE]

### VB6.0 Form Code

```
Option Explicit

Public Event Onvb2py(ByVal val As Variant)
Public Event Onpy2vb(ByVal val As Variant)
Public Event OnClose(ByVal idx As Integer)

Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
      Unload Me
      RaiseEvent OnClose(0)
End Sub

Private Sub cmdPY2VB_Click()
      Text1.Text = pyvalue
      RaiseEvent Onpy2vb(pyvalue)
End Sub

Private Sub cmdVB2PY_Click()
      RaiseEvent Onvb2py(Text1.Text)
End Sub
```

---

VB6.0 Class Code

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents fm As Form1

Event Onvb2py(ByVal val As Variant)
Event Onpy2vb(ByVal val As Variant)
Event OnClose(ByVal idx As Integer)

Private mpy As Variant

Public Sub Show()
      fm.Show
End Sub

Public Sub SetPyValue(ByVal val As Variant)
      mpy = val
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
      Set fm = New Form1
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
      If Not fm Is Nothing Then
            Set fm = Nothing
      End If
End Sub

Private Sub fm_OnClose(ByVal idx As Integer)
      Unload fm
      RaiseEvent OnClose(idx)
End Sub

Private Sub fm_Onpy2vb(ByVal val As Variant)

      RaiseEvent Onpy2vb(val)
      fm.Text1 = mpy
End Sub

Private Sub fm_Onvb2py(ByVal val As Variant)
      RaiseEvent Onvb2py(val)
End Sub
```

---

### Call Python Code

```
import win32com.client

vbcom = win32com.client.Dispatch("nVBCOM.clsConn")
vbevent = win32com.client.WithEvents(vbcom,VBEventHandler)

class VBEventHandler:
    def Onpy2vb(self,val):
        val = "python...value"
        vbcom.SetPyValue(val)

    def Onvb2py(self,val):
        print "vbvalue 2 python : " + val

    def OnClose(self,val):
        print "Close"

def run():
    try:
        vbcom.SetPyValue("Intial py value")
        vbcom.Show()
    except:
        print "Error"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```